# What is move_iterator for

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, move-semantics

If I understand it correct, `a=std::move(b)` binds reference a to the address of b. And after this operation the content that b points to is not guaranteed.

The implementation of `move_iterator` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/move_iterator/) has this line

```
auto operator[](difference_type n) const -> decltype(std::move(current[n]))
  { return std::move(current[n]); }
```

However, I don't think it makes sense to `std::move` an element in an array. What happens if `a=std::move(b[n])`?

The following example confuses me also:

```
std::string concat = std::accumulate(
                             std::move_iterator<iter_t>(source.begin()),
                             std::move_iterator<iter_t>(source.end()),
                             std::string("1234"));
```

Since the `concat` will itself allocate a continuous chunk of memory to store the result, which will not have any overlap with `source`. The data in `source` will be copied to `concat` but not moved.

Comment: *"If I understand it correct, `a=std::move(b)` binds reference `a` to the address of `b`."* Only if this is a declaration, and `a` is of reference type. Otherwise, it is a move-assignment. E.g. if `a` and `b` are `std::vector<int>`, the pointer to the heap storage the vector manages is copied from `b` to `a`, and `b` is changed to point to somewhere else.

Comment: Iterators are an abstraction of pointers. Dereferencing a pointer yields an *lvalue*: `int i = 42; int* p = &i;` then `*i` is an lvalue. Similarly for iterators. But that means that the algorithms will typically copy the values iterators refer to. `move_iterator` makes `*it` return an rvalue.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> If I understand it correct, `a=std::move(b)` binds reference `a` to the address of `b`.  And after this operation the content that b points to is not guaranteed.

Ah, no: `a` is not *necessarily* a reference.  The above use of `std::move` also grants the compiler permission to call `decltype(a)::operator=(decltype(b)&&)` if it exists: such assignment operators are used when during the assignment to `a` the value of `b` need not be preserved, but `b` must still be left in *some* sane state for destruction.

> However, I don't think it makes sense to `std::move` an element in an array. What happens if `a=std::move(b[n])`?

It can make sense... it just means that each array elements may be efficiently assigned/moved to another variable, but only once per element.  After they've been moved-from, a properly-written move constructor or assignment operator should leave objects in a valid but unspecified state, which means you'd usually want to set them again before reading from them.

My [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50071903/410767) shows how someone could append/move elements from a `list` to a `vector`.  With current C++ Standards, you can create move_iterators directly like that.

The code below shows how - even with older compilers / C++ Standards - `make_move_iterator` can be used with `std::copy` if you want to move from the elements in the source iterator range.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct X
{
    X(int n) : n_(n) { }
    X(const X& rhs) : n_(rhs.n_) { }
    X(X&& rhs) : n_{ rhs.n_ } { rhs.n_ *= -1; std::cout << "=(X&&) "; }
    X& operator=(X&& rhs) { n_ = rhs.n_; rhs.n_ *= -1; std::cout << "=(X&&) "; return *this; }
    int n_;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<X> v{2, 1, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    std::vector<X> v2{};

    std::copy(v.begin() + 2, v.end(), std::insert_iterator(v2, v2.end()));
    for (auto& x : v)
        std::cout << x.n_ << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::copy(std::make_move_iterator(v.begin() + 2), std::make_move_iterator(v.end()), std::insert_iterator(v2, v2.end()));
    for (auto& x : v)
        std::cout << x.n_ << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2 1 8 3 4 5 6 
=(X&&) =(X&&) =(X&&) =(X&&) =(X&&) 2 1 -8 -3 -4 -5 -6
```

Code can be run / edited on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe1bc694166f93a5).

Comment: Now I understand, I thought with std move, compiler would do some magic to swap the memory of two lvalue variables. It turns out that the magic is done through copy constructor that takes an rvalue. Which means it won't work on plain old types. For example, if b is an int array, a=std::move(b[n]) would be the same as a=b[n].

Comment: @MinLin: copy constructors and assignment operators are the most obvious uses for "move magic".  As you say - they don't make operations on `int`s more efficient - only types where there's some way to take ownership of data without as much copying or allocation/deallocation.

Comment: @MinLin: Notice that "copy constructor that takes an rvalue" is exactly what we mean when we say "move constructor." What you said is an unusual, but perfectly cromulent, way of putting it. :)
(Although, also notice, we're talking about *assignment* operators here. So you could have said "copy assignment operator that takes an rvalue", or "move assignment operator" — again, both perfectly accurate descriptors.)

Comment: `remove_if` would move anyway, so i don't see a gain

Comment: @Yola: true now - maybe ideone (the online compiler I used back in 2015) was using an old compiler version that hadn't updated remove_if to do that - can't remember for sure.  But, I've replaced the example to show how it can be used in combination with `std::copy`.

Comment: Without disagreeing with anything wrote, note that     `std::copy(std::make_move_iterator(v.begin() + 2), std::make_move_iterator(v.end()), std::insert_iterator(v2, v2.end()));` should be equivalent to `std::move(v.begin() + 2, v.end(), std::insert_iterator(v2, v2.end()));`

Answer (score 11):

The purpose of `move_iterator` is to supply algorithms with rvalues of their inputs.

Your example `auto a=std::move(b[n])` does not move a value in an array but moves it out of it, which is a sensible thing to do.

The trick in your `std::accumulate` is the definition of [operator+ for std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) (remember that the default version of accumulate uses `operator+`. It has a special optimization for rvalue arguments. For our case overload number 7 is the important one since `accumulate` uses the expression `init + *begin`. This will try to reuse the memory of the right hand side argument. If this actually turns out to be an optimization is not really clear.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between `aVector.push_back(std::move(*it))` and `aVector.push_back(*std::make_move_iterator(it))` ?

Answer (score 10):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator says this:

> std::move_iterator is an iterator adaptor which behaves exactly like the underlying iterator (which must be at least an InputIterator), except that dereferencing converts the value returned by the underlying iterator into an rvalue.

Most (if not all) standard algorithms that accept a range, walk an iterator from the beginning of the range to the end, and perform an operation on the dereferenced iterator. For example, `std::accumulate` might be implemented as:

```
template <class InputIterator, class T>
T accumulate (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, T init)
{
  while (first!=last) {
    init = init + *first;
    ++first;
  }
  return init;
}
```

If `first` and `last` are normal iterators (the call was

```
std::accumulate(source.begin(), source.end(), std::string("1234"));
```

, then `*first` is an lvalue reference to string, and the expression `init + *first` will call `std::operator+(std::string const&, std::string const&)` (overload 1 [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B)).

However, if the call was

```
std::accumulate(std::make_move_iterator(source.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(source.end()), std::string("1234"));
```

then inside std::accumulate, `first` and `last` are move iterators and therefore `*first` is an rvalue reference. This means that `init + *first` calls `std::operator+(std::string const&, std::string &&)` instead (overload 7).

Comment: In fact, overload 7 (where lhs is an lvalue [string const&] and rhs is an rvalue [string &&]) is implemented like this: `return std::move(rhs.insert(0, lhs));` in order to avoid having to copy the (const) lhs before modification. Instead, it modifies the (temporary) rhs and then steals from it.

Comment: Overload 8 (where both strings are temporary rvalues) is even smarter: it either inserts lhs into rhs or appends rhs to lhs depending on which string has enough capacity for the entire result.