# insert list to end of vector

Tags: c++, stl

Is there an easy way to insert an entire list to the end of a vector without inserting the front value and popping it for the entire list? Right now, I'm doing thing:

```
std::vector<int> v({1,2,3});
std::list<int> l({5,7,9});
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    v.push_back(l.front());
    l.pop_front();
}
```

I'm hoping for some way to easily just iterate through the list and insert it into the vector.

Comment: `v.insert(v.end(), l.begin(). l.end());`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: that should be an answer, not a comment ;-).  Worth mentioning it won't remove anything from the list, so you'll want to call `l.clear()` as well to end up in a the same state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to insert at the end of `v`. Both `vector` and `list` have iterators so its pretty straight forward.

You can replace your for loop with this single line:

```
v.insert(v.end(), l.begin(), l.end());
```

Here is the updated code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    std::vector<int> v({1,2,3});
    std::list<int> l({5,7,9});

    v.insert(v.end(), l.begin(), l.end());
    l.clear();

    for (int i : v) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
Hello, World!
1 2 3 5 7 9 
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Answer (score 6):

While the question illustrated `int` element types, that might have been a simplification while preparing an example, or other readers might find this Q&A when wanting to [*move*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2027.html#Move_Semantics) non-copyable elements from the list, or types likes `std::string` that can often<sup>1</sup> be moved faster than copied.  To move elements, use:

```
v.insert(v.end(),
         std::move_iterator{l.begin()}, std::move_iterator{l.end()});
l.clear();
```

---

<sup>1</sup> in `string`'s case - when longer than any internal Short-String-Optimisation buffer and therefore using dynamically allocated memory

Answer (score 2):

Another way -- maybe you can just use the initializer list directly

```
v.insert(v.end(), {5,7,9});
```

You can also use `std::copy`

```
std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), std::back_inserter(v));
l.clear();
```